# How to extract port from IP:PORT after a specific string?

Tags: bash, grep

I have a file like this;

```
someip=[2a05:6a4:2a3a:53asd:0:0:0:1]
someip=[2a05:6a4:2a3a:123a:0:0:0:1]
someip=192.168.1.1
someip=192.167.2.1

anotherip=127.0.0.1:1234
```

and I want to extract only `1234` and pass it into a variable. I usually do this with this command;

```sh
grep -o -E '[^:]+$' file.txt
```

This would return `1234` if there wasn't those IPs in `someip=`. Because of them, it tries to return those IP addresses too.

How can I only extract `1234` from this file? Maybe there's a way to make this grep command work only on a line that contains the string `anotherip=` ?

Or is there a way to get only `1234` from the below string? (but this `1234` can be different like `12345`, `578214` etc)

```
something something 127.0.0.1:1234 something something something
```

Answer (score 2):

Using the Perl mode supported by some versions of `grep`:

```
grep -P -o ':\K\d+$'
```

Look for lines which end in a colon followed by a string of digits and discard the colon and everything that appears before it.

Answer (score 0):

An `awk` version

```
awk -F":" '/:[0-9]+/ && !/]/ {print $2}' file
1234
```